# Python: sum over arrays element by element

Tags: python, arrays, aggregation

I have some probability output of 5 models, and I sum of the probabilities element by element like below:

```
probs = [None] * 5

for i in range(0,5):
  probs[i] = models[i].predict_proba(X)

probs[0] + probs[1] + probs[2] + probs[3] + probs[4]
```

This works fine.

I then tried to simplified the above code a bit by doing below:

```
probs = [None] * 5
results = [None]

for i in range(0,5):
  probs[i] = models[i].predict_proba(X)
  results += probs[i]

results
```

But got the following error:

```
TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float' 
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-8d4d443a7428> in <module>()
      4 for i in range(0,5):
      5   probs[i] = models[i].predict_proba(X)
----> 6   results += probs[i]
      7 
      8 results

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

How could I fix such error? Thanks.

```
Note: 

probs[i] is of format:

array([[  9.99877759e-01,   1.22241455e-04],
       [  9.99694005e-01,   3.05994629e-04],
       [  9.47546608e-01,   5.24533925e-02],
       [  1.83994998e-01,   8.16005002e-01],
       [  9.66928729e-01,   3.30712706e-02],
       [  9.99487283e-01,   5.12717255e-04],
       [  2.85824823e-03,   9.97141752e-01],
       [  9.97979081e-01,   2.02091861e-03],
       [  9.99744813e-01,   2.55186665e-04]])
```

Comment: Why is results a list? Shouldn't it be a float?

Comment: Just set `results = 0` and your code will run fine. However, you should really consider the answers below as they are more pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to add a `float` to `None`.  You can simplify your code greatly using a list comprehension:

```
probs = [models[i].predict_proba(X) for i in range(5)]
```

And then to get the sum, just `sum(probs)`

Answer (score 2):

You assigned `[None]` as your `result` at the beginning, and then try to add it immediately in the first iteration of the for loop, and that causes the error message.

Instead, you can try use list comprehension since using Python:

```
result = sum([models[i].predict_proba(X) for i in range(5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined result as a list, but it should be a float type.
Try this:

```
results = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem:

```
probs = [None] * 5
results = np.zeros(data.shape)

for i in range(0,5):
  probs[i] = models[i].predict_proba(X)
  results += probs[i]

results
```

Where, `data.shape` should be the expected shape of the result from `models[i].predict_proba(X)`.